# undefined symbol for self-built llvm opt?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, llvm

I write a simple llvm plugin pass that requires *opt* to load `xxx.so` file and run a ModulePass. The strange thing is that when I use `deb` package `opt` (e.g., from `apt-get`, let's call it `opt-3.7`), the plugin works fine (the drawback is that it is a **Release** build); however when I use the *opt* I build myself (simplify call it `opt`), it frequently complains:

```
Error opening 'xxx.so': xxx.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm12FunctionPass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

using `c++filt` I know that `opt` cannot find `llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass(llvm::raw_ostream&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const`.

It's a big strange since I didn't use any `FunctionPass` in the pass; but let's ignore this and continue.

I then checked the result of `ldd opt`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd5c1ce000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f16a90d3000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f16a8ea9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f16a8c8c000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f16a8a72000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f16a86ef000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f16a83e6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f16a81d0000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f16a7e06000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005645f6210000)
```

and `ldd opt-3.7`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc51bc0000)
libLLVM-3.7.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.7.so.1 (0x00007fec3f725000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fec3f3a2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fec3efb1000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fec3ed97000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fec3eb79000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fec3e971000)
libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0x00007fec3e739000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fec3e50f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fec3e30b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fec3e002000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fec3ddeb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055bad2080000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fec3dbd6000)
```

The difference, I guess, is the so file `libLLVM-3.7.so.1`.

So where didn't I get wrong?

BTW, my llvm was built w/o and w/ `-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=1`, both has the undefined symbol issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had exactly the same error when using LLVM plugin with CLANG 3.9. We then found the solution here: https://github.com/klee/klee/issues/336

The explanation is that ABI for libstdc++ used for LLVM and your plugin is different. To solve this problem you need to recompile your plugin with the following flag "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0".

Check this Makefile for LLVM plugin as example: https://github.com/SamAinsworth/reproduce-cgo2017-paper/blob/master/package/plugin-llvm-sw-prefetch-pass/Makefile