# Undefined symbol for LLVM plugin

Tags: llvm-clang

I trying to build an open source LLVM plugin (https://github.com/HewlettPackard/Atlas). 
But when I try to build using the llvm plugin I get an "error: unable to load plugin... undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm12FunctionPass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKSs" (llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass). 
This is likely caused by the different ABI problem mentioned here: [undefined symbol for self-built llvm opt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366291/undefined-symbol-for-self-built-llvm-opt), but building the plugin with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 does not solve the problem.

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I tried clang version 3.6, 3.8 and 3.9 and the problem persists.

Building: (with clang++3.6, 3.8, 3.9, with and without -stdlib=libstdc++, with and without -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)

```
clang++-3.9 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -c src/Instrumentation/NvmInstrumenter.cpp -I/usr/lib/llvm-3.9/include -fPIC  -std=c++11 

clang++-3.9 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -shared NvmInstrumenter.o -o NvmInstrumenter.so

clang++-3.9  -Xclang -load -Xclang ./NvmInstrumenter.so  -o oo -c ./r.cpp
```

The last line results in the undefined symbol error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even suggestions on which direction to continue looking will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I found that I didn't put "-fno-rtti" during compilation. http://llvm.1065342.n5.nabble.com/llvm-dev-Undefined-symbol-error-while-running-the-pass-td92634.html

Comment: Clang uses it's own internal object identification scheme, rtti actually should be disabled for anything linking to clang or llvm objects