# Undefined symbol when loading LLVM plugin

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, abi

I am developing an LLVM pass and want to run it as a plugin via the Clang LLVM driver:

```
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang myPlugin.so ...
```

At first I got an error similar to that described here

- [undefined symbol for self-built llvm opt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366291/undefined-symbol-for-self-built-llvm-opt)

After applying the flag `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` as suggested, I'm getting this error:

```
error: unable to load plugin 'myPlugin.so': 'myPlugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm12FunctionPass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKSs
```

This page suggests that there may be an ABI compatibility issue (which I don't fully understand)

- http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Loading-Static-Analyzer-plugin-fails-with-CommandLine-Errors-td4034194.html

My objective is to compile the pass with either GCC or Clang and run it with the system Clang installation (Ubuntu 16.04, LLVM 3.8) rather than building Clang/LLVM from source.

Comment: My `c++filt` on MacOS & Ubuntu 16.04 can't decode `_ZNK4llvm12FunctionPass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKNSt7`

Comment: oops my bad, edited the question :)

Comment: it gives this `llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass(llvm::raw_ostream&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const`

Answer (score 0):

The problem could come from multiple clang installations. The `clang` version you have used to compile your plugin may be different from the `clang` called in

```
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang myPlugin.so ...
```

If you use `cmake` to build your plugin, then

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

will generate the file `compile_commands.json` that will contain the llvm version you have used. `bear make` or `make -n` are alternatives if you don't use `cmake` for your plugin.

If `compile_commands.json` contains for example

```
"command": "c++ -c -I/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/include ..."
```

and if `clang -v` is `clang version 3.8.0`, you are likely to obtain this error message especially if `llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass` is in llvm-4.0 and not in llvm-3.8.

A solution may be to compile with

```
clang-xxx -Xclang -load -Xclang myPlugin.so ...
```

where `clang-xxx` contains the `llvm-xxx` that is referenced in `compile_commands.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving that error because first argument I passed into the RegisterPass had the same name as the pass itself:

```
static RegisterPass<MyPass> X("MyPass", "DPVariableNamePass", false, false);
```

Changing it fixed the issue:

```
static RegisterPass<MyPass> X("my-pass", "DPVariableNamePass", false, false);
```

Maybe it helps