# Failed to test llvm LLVMHello pass, lib/LLVMHello.so: undefined symbol:

Tags: c++, ubuntu, llvm

I want to write a llvm pass,  and test the example as http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html. But it failed to run the pass, and the result is as follow:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Documents$ opt -load llvm-5.0.0.src/build/lib/LLVMHello.so -hello < Test/hello.bc > /dev/null
Error opening 'llvm-5.0.0.src/build/lib/LLVMHello.so': llvm-5.0.0.src/build/lib/LLVMHello.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm12FunctionPass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
  -load request ignored.
opt: Unknown command line argument '-hello'.  Try: 'opt -help'
opt: Did you mean '-help'?
```

---

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Documents$ opt -version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 5.0.0
  DEBUG build with assertions.
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: broadwell
```

Comment: How did you build LLVMHello?

Comment: @Brian, the LLVMHello.so is build as default when building LLVM.

Comment: Ok.  Are you using the same opt that you built from source?
Your issue looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366291/undefined-symbol-for-self-built-llvm-opt

Comment: @Brian, Yes, I try to rebuild the llvm, and the problem is gone. Thanks

Comment: @Stuartly How did you rebuild your llvm? I have the same problem and I am not able to figure out the solution.